# Register annotation router

Tags: php, routes, phalcon

I want to use the annotation router and I follow the example from the documentation http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html#annotations-router.

I have a multi module application and keep getting 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class IndexController does not exist'.

Have anyone experienced the same problem? How did you solve it?

router

```
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Annotations();
$router->addModuleResource('frontend', 'Index');
$di->set('router', $router);
```

frontend/controllers/IndexController.php

```
/**
 * @Get("/:action")
 */
    public function indexAction()
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information found in the phalcon forum: http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/344/multi-module-wildcard-annotation-router

One has to register the namespace with the Phalcon\Loader instead of the throught the modules loader.

```
    $loader = new Loader();

    $loader->registerNamespaces(
        array(
            'Apps\Backend\Controllers' => __dir__ . '/../apps/backend/controllers/'
        )
    );

    $loader->register();
```